# Modal popup on failed login attempt

Tags: javascript, php

#### Problem:

I have a login form, which checks for 3 conditions before login in, if the pass is correct, if correct is the user enabled or verified, what I want to do is have a contact-us modal pop up if the user is not verified yet.

#### Headers from the action.php

```
header('location: control-panel.php');
    }else{
        header('location: index.php?inactive=');
    }
    }else{
        header('location: index.php?dis');
    }
    }else{
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['isactive'] = false;
        header('location: index.php?err=1');
    }   
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

#### From the form page

```
<?php
$error = 0;

if (isset($_REQUEST['err'])){  
    $error = $_REQUEST['err'];
}
$dis = echo '<script>
$(window).on('load',function(){
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('shown-modal')){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    sessionStorage.setItem('shown-modal', 'true');
}
});
</script> ;

$inactive = 'Sorry Your Account Has Not Been Activated Yet<br /> Check Your Mail And Click On The Activation Link To Activate Your Account';

?>
```

#### Attempt:

```
$dis = echo '<script>
$(window).on('load',function(){
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem('shown-modal')){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        sessionStorage.setItem('shown-modal', 'true');
    }
});
</script> ;
```

Comment: You should post more of the code you have in context. Despite the quote issue, the logic on these are strange. You assign `$error = $_REQUEST['err'];` but don't seem to use it anywhere, same with `$inactive`. Then you are echoing the javascript section, but also assigning it to `$dis` and presumably the header snippet is just different parts of a larger script? It would all be syntax errors...

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to the usages of `"` and `'`:

#### Attempt 1

```
echo "<script>
    $(window).on('load',function(){
      if (!sessionStorage.getItem('shown-modal')){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        sessionStorage.setItem('shown-modal', 'true');
      }
    });
  </script>";
```

#### Output 1

```
<script>
  $(window).on('load',function(){
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem('shown-modal')){
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      sessionStorage.setItem('shown-modal', 'true');
    }
  });
</script>
```

#### Attempt 2

```
echo '<script>
      $(window).on("load",function(){
        if (!sessionStorage.getItem("shown-modal")){
          $("#myModal").modal("show");
          sessionStorage.setItem("shown-modal", "true");
        }
      });
</script>';
```

#### Output 2

```
<script>
  $(window).on("load",function(){
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem("shown-modal")){
      $("#myModal").modal("show");
      sessionStorage.setItem("shown-modal", "true");
    }
  });
</script>
```